# How to set graph y an x limits using variables

Tags: python, matplotlib

> Hi all guys here. I wan to know if it's possible to set new char limits using variable value every time I update a graph. Below follow my code, I can run it and plot new graph with variables, but my legend stay in the middle of data, so I don't want to change legend position then my idea was to set new y na x axis limit to fit my legend. I would thank any help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Importando os pacotes
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


#Setting GPIO pins
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN) 
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN) 

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)


#Setting time count variables
t1fvm = 0.0
t1ivm = 0.0
mevm = 0.0
levm = 0

t2fvm = 0.0
t2ivm = 0.0
mdvm = 0.0
ldvm = 0


#Setting Bar chart variables
ptotal_1 = 20.0
ptotal_2 = 15.0
somatoria_1 = 3.0
somatoria_2 = 6.0


#Setting buttons functions
def lev():

    if GPIO.input(17):

        t1fvm = time.time()
        global levm
        global t1ivm
        global mevm
        n1mv = (t1fvm-t1ivm)
        mevm = mevm+n1mv
        levm = int(float(mevm))
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)

    else:
        t1ivm = time.time()
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)

def ldv():

    if GPIO.input(27):
        t2fvm = time.time()
        global ldvm
        global t2ivm
        global mdvm
        n2mv = (t2fvm-t2ivm)
        mdvm = mdvm+n2mv
        ldvm = int(float(mdvm))
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)

    else:
        t2ivm = time.time()
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)



class showAcionam(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "SmartLight")
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side = "top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)



        sairFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.sairFrame = sairFrame
        sairFrame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        sair = ttk.Button(sairFrame, text="Sair")
        menuu = ttk.Button(sairFrame, text="Menu",
                               command = lambda: self.show_frame(Menu))
        menuu.pack(side="left", expand = True)

        frame = Acionamento(container, self)

        self.frames[Acionamento] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Acionamento)


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()




class Acionamento(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Alarmes")
        label.pack()


        esquerdaFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.esquerdaFrame = esquerdaFrame
        esquerdaFrame.pack(side ="left", fill="both", expand=True, pady=50, padx=30)

        direitaFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.direitaFrame = direitaFrame
        direitaFrame.pack(side ="left", fill="both", expand=True, pady=50, padx=30)

        modoFrame = tk.Frame(direitaFrame)
        self.direitaFrame.modoFrame = modoFrame
        modoFrame.pack(side ="top", fill="both", expand=True, pady=15, padx=10)

        setorFrame = tk.Frame(direitaFrame)
        self.direitaFrame.setorFrame = setorFrame
        setorFrame.pack(side ="top", fill="both", expand=True, pady=15, padx=10)


        #- Liga e Desliga
        onButton_1 = tk.Button(direitaFrame, text = "Button 1", height=2, width=6, command=lev)
        onButton_1.pack(side="top", expand = True)

        #- Liga e Desliga
        onButton_2 = tk.Button(direitaFrame, text = "Button 2", height=2, width=6, command=ldv)
        onButton_2.pack(side="top", expand = True)

        #Defining tkinter chart
        f = Figure(figsize=(4, 3), dpi=100)
        modo= f.add_subplot(111)
        self.modo = modo

        width = 0.5

        grafico_operacao = modo.bar(ptotal_1, somatoria_1, width, color='r')
        self.grafico_operacao = grafico_operacao
        grafico_operacao1 = modo.bar(ptotal_2+width, somatoria_2, color='g')
        self.grafico_operacao1 = grafico_operacao1

        modo.set_xlabel('Tempo (H)')
        modo.set_ylabel('Energia Consumida (KW.H)')
        modo.set_title('Consumo por Modo de Operação')
        modo.legend((grafico_operacao[0], grafico_operacao1[0]),('1', '2'))

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, modoFrame)
        self.canvas = canvas
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, modoFrame)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)




        ## Functio which should write new graph with new values. Here I want to set new x and y axis min and max values. How can I perform it using variables?
        def Grafico():

            global somatoria_1
            global somatoria_2
            global ptotal_1
            global ptotal_2

            ptotal_1 = (ptotal_1*somatoria_1)
            ptotal_2 = (ptotal_2*somatoria_2)
            somatoria_1 = (levm/3600)
            somatoria_2 = (ldvm/3600)

            modo.clear()

            width = 0.5

            grafico_operacao = modo.bar(ptotal_1, somatoria_1, width, color='r')
            self.grafico_operacao = grafico_operacao
            grafico_operacao1 = modo.bar(ptotal_2+width, somatoria_2, color='g')
            self.grafico_operacao1 = grafico_operacao1


            modo.set_xlabel('Tempo (H)')
            modo.set_ylabel('Energia Consumida (KW.H)')
            modo.set_title('Consumo por Modo de Operação')
            modo.legend((grafico_operacao[0], grafico_operacao1[0]),('1', '2'))

            canvas.show()

        #-Atualizar
        atualizarv = tk.Button(esquerdaFrame, text = "Atualizar", height=2, width=6, command=Grafico)
        atualizarv.pack(side="top", expand = True)



app = showAcionam()
app.geometry("800x600")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: IOBE, what's the code problem? I would thank if you could help me.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Describe what you want to do, how you do it, and what you expect. Clearly state in how far the result of your code does not meet those expectations. Mention what other people have already done to solve that problem and in how far it doesn't help you.
Create a *minimal* *verifiable* example. Your code is not *minimal*, as it uses tons of imports and variables not needed to reproduce the problem.
Your code is not *verifiable*, as it uses objects other users cannot verify. Since those are not needed to reproduce the problem, leave them out.

Comment: Ok IOBE, please have a look now at code.